# Change Internet Explorer settings programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, internet-explorer

Any idea how do I do the following using C#?

1. Going  to `Tools -> Internet Options -> Security`
2. Select the `Security` tab
3. Click the `Custom Level` button
4. In the `Miscellaneous` section change `Display mixed content` to `Enable`

Comment: You mean, from within a trusted, locally installed C# app that has administrator rights?

Comment: Yes. trusted local app running with admin privileges

Comment: And, of course, this would be a "temporary change"... which is ALLWAYS undone after it's served it's purpose? I wouldn't go "adjusting" the users browser settings, especially security sensitive ones, without the users INFORMED consent.

Comment: Lots of lecturing as responses.  This might be non-published code used for testing purposes.  There are legitimate reasons to want to do such things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "cheat" way to do this is to change the value

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\0\1609
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\1\1609
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\2\1609
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\3\1609
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\4\1609

Where 0-4 are Zone identifiers and the value is 0 to Allow, 1 to Prompt, and 3 to Block. Keep in mind that if your code does this on anyone's machine but your own, you're likely to find your code blocked as malware.

The "proper" way to do this is to use the APIs to create an IInternetZoneManager and call [SetZoneActionPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537086%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to adjust the settings for URLACTION_HTML_MIXED_CONTENT in the zones you want to adjust.

Comment: A list of all the registry values and a description for each can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569). Also note that each zone represents a distinct _security zone_. `Zone 3` is the `Internet Zone`.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't supposed to do this "programmatically". That's why there isn't an API for it. Only the user can change their security settings, and they do it using the built-in interface that you've already discovered.

The poor IE team has been working overtime trying to tighten up the security of their browser. They're not going to throw in something like this that would nullify all of their efforts in a matter of seconds.
Recall that even once this option is selected, there's [a confirmation dialog presented](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/05/14/mixed-content-and-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx). How do you propose to "click" that programmatically? (Hmm, on second thought, don't tell me. That's probably the next question you'll be asking.)

Give up on trying to do this programmatically, and ask the user to do it themselves. Provide a complete help file or other documentation that explains why you're requesting that they make this change, what features will be unavailable if they do not choose to make this change, and what the possible security risks of making such a change are. And, of course, specific instructions on how the change is made.

Or, better yet, redesign your app so that it doesn't require a **system-wide** modification of IE's security settings. It's hard to imagine a legitimate case for this. A better solution might be asking the user to add your site to their "trusted sites". Remember that local pages have different security settings than remote pages by default.

Comment: Goofy.  As someone that just spent an hour going cross eyed and hoping I got all those settings the way <big-company> wants them... I'd say.. even after all these years (it's 2018 now) <big-company> security doesn't seem to have a way to MONITOR / MANAGE these settings.  It's a crime.  I should be able to run the config-ie.exe and both myself and <big-company> rest assured the settings are what they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Also do not forget Group Policies. Most (if not all) IE settings may also be specified in Group Policies.
According to [Local group policy setting for IE security page vs Internet options security page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/80d104e6-41f9-49c5-b15e-e8eff6ef33a0/local-group-policy-setting-for-ie-security-page-vs-internet-options-security-page?forum=winserverGP)
the Group Policy settings override user-defined settings.
So, on my home PC (works without domain controller) I have a choice to define IE settings either via Local Group Policy Editor or via Internet Options. For example, if I run gpedit.msc to open Local Group Policy Editor, select
Computer Configuration\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Page\Internet Zone
change "Display mixed content"  setting to "Enabled", then select "Enable" in drop down box, click Apply,
then open Security Settings for Internet Zone in IE - I will see that "Display mixed content" changed to Enable and
the selection is disabled because it is overriden by Policy.
For the entire list of supported policies download WindowsServer2012andWindows8GroupPolicySettings.xlsx
from
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250

Now back to the question how to change settings programmatically.
EricLaw correctly suggested using SetZoneActionPolicy from IInternetZoneManager.
But it is hard to find samples for calling it from C#.
I ended up copying
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces.IInternetZoneManager
into my code and then doing:

```
//This will disable "Download signed ActiveX" (IE setting # 0x1001) for Internet Zone (zone #3)
IInternetZoneManager izm = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("7b8a2d95-0ac9-11d1-896c-00c04Fb6bfc4"))) as IInternetZoneManager;
IntPtr pPolicy = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
Marshal.Copy(new int[] { 3 }, 0, pPolicy, 1);//3 means "Disable"
int result = izm.SetZoneActionPolicy((uint)UrlZone.Internet, (uint)0x1001, pPolicy, 4, (uint)UrlZoneReg.CurrentUserKey);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(izm);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pPolicy);
```

I also tried changing group policy programmatically.
I used library from
https://bitbucket.org/MartinEden/local-policy
and then:

```
//This will disable "Download signed ActiveX controls" computer policy for Internet Zone (zone #3)
const string keyPath = @"SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3";
var gpo = new LocalPolicy.ComputerGroupPolicyObject();
using (var machine = gpo.GetRootRegistryKey(LocalPolicy.GroupPolicySection.Machine))
{
    using (var terminalServicesKey = machine.CreateSubKey(keyPath))
    {
        terminalServicesKey.SetValue("1001", 3, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
}
gpo.Save();
```

After successfully testing the code above on Win7 SP1 with IE 11 I decided to go back to the original suggestion from EricLaw: modify
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\*\1001
directly because this is what Microsoft is recommending. See, for example [How to strengthen the security settings for the Local Machine zone in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833633) or [Enhanced Browsing Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457150.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I think you can find all these settings in "registry". You need to find out the appropriate key. And to change those values you need to have proper rights. Registry can be accessed from .net code

Comment: The settings are under sub keys at - HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings;

Comment: Remember that modifications to the Registry do not take effect immediately. The settings in the Registry are generally read once at system startup and cached. This is not the correct way to change system settings.

Comment: It depends on the application and the keys. Some reg keys which are used by OS will require you to start the OS again as OS has read them once and cached their values. Reg keys which are used by some application will only require to restart the application. Registry is just a general storage area, how the data is used depends on the consumer of the data (OS, apps etc). But obviously it is not a good way of changing some other app setting by directly modifying its reg keys.

Comment: Gee, yeah, it obviously depends on the app. But we're not talking about application configuration settings. We're talking about Internet Explorer's system-wide security settings. The point is, this is not the correct way to modify those settings. You found an undocumented hack, hurray. The problem with this are those typical of undocumented hacks. Searching the registry for the settings you want is not the right way of finding new functionality in Windows. Read [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) for details.

Comment: I agree with you. Don't do this.. but is good to know all this stuff. I would never do this in my app. using undocumented way of doing this is bad and will only lead to issues